# Invited owner of firebase project can't deploy cloud functions

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, firebase-tools

I have a firebase project where I invited a developer as an owner. He got email and accepted the invitation. Yet he can't deploy functions to that project. He also tried with different internet connections. It's failing with the error below....

**! functions: Upload Error: Server Error. read ECONNRESET**
**Error: Server Error. read ECONNRESET**

*firebase-debug.log*

```
[debug] [2020-05-13T23:49:33.202Z] >>> HTTP REQUEST PUT https://storage.googleapis.com/gcf-upload-us-central1....
 <request body omitted>
[warn] !  functions: Upload Error: Server Error. read ECONNRESET
[debug] [2020-05-13T23:49:55.186Z] Error: read ECONNRESET
    at TLSWrap.onStreamRead (internal/stream_base_commons.js:111:27)
[error] 
[error] Error: Server Error. read ECONNRESET
```

index.js file contains a simple function that was generated automatically by **firebase init** command.This is what index.js file contains..

```
const functions = require("firebase-functions");

exports.helloWorld = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
  response.send("Hello from Firebase!");
});
```

Comment: I don't immediately see anything in what you shared that hints at the problem coming from how you added the user. You might want to the developer to create their own project and see if they can deploy the [basic example function](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/get-started) to that. If not, the problem is more likely on their end, and not in your project.

Comment: Thank you sir for your comment. He can't deploy functions in his own project. Does it mean that he needs to change network ?

Comment: Are you sure that he is trying to deploy just this `helloWorld` function? if yes, than I would guess this is a matter of his environment. He should try to deploy this `helloWorld` from newly fresh system like from some VM to check is it a matter of permissions.

Comment: yes, it's just a helloWorld function as stated above. Now even I myself can't deploy function in any project. I have tried with 3 other devices and 3 other networks. but still facing the same problem.

Comment: I can only confirm that "helloWorld" function is working on my side. I suggest to create new project and try to go trough https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/get-started. If it won't work contact Firebase Support.

Comment: Thanks for your reply sir. There was a problem with the google api link in my country. For some reason, these google's API was blocked here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was a problem with the google api link in my country. For some reason, these google API were blocked here.